# While running the Ubuntu-Tweak Janitor, it got hanged, Why?

Tags: 14.04, software-sources, ubuntu-tweak

I have tried to clean the files via Ubuntu-Tweak Janitor,
but it got hanged **while adding personal** and after using xkill only it gets cleared.

Why so? Any Solution to rectify it? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have rectified the problem which was occurred due to missing of certain files and invalid file permission.

Now, It works fine.